# JQuery Append html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a matrix of tags `<a href="">`, generated by this code in `JQuery`:

```
function makeList(){
    var listContainer = $("#matrix");
    for(i=0; i<10; ++i){
        listContainer.append( $("<nav><ul> <li><a href="">v1</li> 
            <li><a href="">v2</li> <li><a href="">v3</li> 
            <li><a href="">v4</li>"));
        console.log("adding...");
    } 
}
```

Now I have 40 `<a href="">` links, and a user click one of them. I need to access to this very `<a href="">` and make something to it.

How can I do it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the elements are getting appended, initially the DOM won't have the elements.
Use [on event handler.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**Syntax:**

`.on('event', 'selector', fn);`

Plus using "**this**" keyword, you can fetch the element which you have just clicked.

```
 $("a").on("click",function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
 });
```

Have appended the elements required and added an event handler in the following [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ht6Ym/3205/).

Comment: Thank you! But how can I save the clicked variable...? I mean, console.log ($(this).html()); is for debugging, but I need to take the variable clicked and make things to it, like change the font color or anything

Comment: @Sergi Look up changing class via jquery. That's the best practice to change font color. "$(this) " contains the element that you need, hence use jquery to do whatever features you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear to me.
If you want to identify which  is clicked the following code snippets may help you.

```js
$("a").on("click",function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a class to the `<a>` tag and use the added class as selector for the click event and access the clicked tag using `this` pointer/reference.

See below example-

```
<a class="test" href="#">Test 1</a>
<a class="test" href="#">Test 2</a>
<a class="test" href="#">Test 3</a>
<a class="test" href="#">Test 4</a>
```

```
$('.test').on('click',function(){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

**Working Fiddle-** http://jsfiddle.net/pp8b7aec/

Answer (score 1):

As you are appending the elements dynamically so you need to use event delegation syntax, because they were not in the dom when page loaded, so any event bound on dynamic elemetns won't be registered.

The syntax is:

```
$(staticParent).on('event', 'selector', fn);
```

so in your case you can do this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#matrix").on('click', 'nav a', function(e){ // register the event on static parent
        e.preventDefault();// stops the link to navigate
        alert(this.textContent); // alert the text written in the clicked link.
    });
});
```

in the code above you can even delegate to the `$("#matrix"), $("body") or $(document)`.